# JavaFX synchronizing two choiceboxes

Tags: java, javafx

So I'm trying to learn java and tried to program my first App. It's supposed to a Converter but I'm running in a little problem. I want to synchronize two chioceboxes so that when I select for example length in the first one I can't select gram in the second one and so on. 
But I don't know how to do this I tried to use to ChangeListner but I don't really understand what I'm doing ;).
It's problaby not the code but I hope you can understand theproblem I'm having right now.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    //Labels
    Label title = new Label("Converter");
    title.setFont(new Font("Cambria", 28));

    Label choice1Label = new Label("Please enter a value");

    Label scene1choice1 = new Label("Please enter your first value:");
    Label scene1choice2 = new Label("Please enter your second value:");

    // Buttons
    Button btnHome = new Button("Next");


    //ChoiceBoxen
    ChoiceBox homeValue = new ChoiceBox();
    homeValue.setValue("length");
    homeValue.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("length", "area", "volume", "weigth"));

    ChoiceBox value1 = new ChoiceBox();



    //V- and HBoxen
    HBox titleBox = new HBox(title);
    titleBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    titleBox.setPadding(new Insets(30));
    titleBox.setSpacing(40);

    HBox fstChoiceLabel = new HBox(choice1Label);
    fstChoiceLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    fstChoiceLabel.setPadding(new Insets(75));
    fstChoiceLabel.setSpacing(70);

    HBox frstchoice = new HBox(homeValue);
    frstchoice.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    frstchoice.setPadding(new Insets(40));
    frstchoice.setSpacing(70);

    HBox fstBtn_Home = new HBox(btnHome);
    fstBtn_Home.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    fstBtn_Home.setPadding(new Insets(40));
    fstBtn_Home.setSpacing(20);

    VBox homeScreen = new VBox(fstChoiceLabel, frstchoice);

    HBox scene1Label1 = new HBox(scene1choice1);
    scene1Label1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    scene1Label1.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    scene1Label1.setSpacing(20);

    HBox scene1Choice1 = new HBox(value1);
    scene1Choice1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    scene1Choice1.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    scene1Choice1.setSpacing(20);


    HBox scene1Label2 = new HBox(value1);
    scene1Label2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    scene1Label2.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    scene1Label2.setSpacing(20);

    HBox scene1Choice2 = new HBox();
    scene1Choice2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    scene1Choice2.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    scene1Choice2.setSpacing(20);

    VBox scene1Label = new VBox(scene1Label1, scene1choice1, scene1Label2, scene1choice2);


    //Scene
    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setTop(titleBox);
    pane.setCenter(homeScreen);
    pane.setBottom(fstBtn_Home);

    BorderPane pane1 = new BorderPane();
    pane1.setCenter(scene1Label);

    BorderPane pane2 = new BorderPane();

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 500);
    Scene scene1 = new Scene(pane1, 300, 500);
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(pane2, 300, 500);

    btnHome.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene1));


    //Window
    primaryStage.setTitle("UMRECHNER");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Comment: There should be some type of on item selected associated with the `ComboBox`.

Comment: I am not sure if the duplicate answer is a quality answer. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: _I tried to use to ChangeListner but I don't really understand what I'm doing_ well, then the step to take is start working through a tutorial that's explaining what/how to do it ;) I don't see __any__ effort in your code that's in any way related to the problem you describe (which is far too broad, anyways). And why two scenes if all you want is sync the content of two choiceBoxes? Write a [mcve] with just those two boxes and wire the listeners (as you learned while working through the tutorial :)

Answer (score 1):

Its an interesting challenge you can solve in multiple ways. I think a cool way is using the observable API by using a `FilteredList`. For example

```
ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("length", "area", "volume", "weigth");

FilteredList<String> fl1 = new FilteredList(items);
fl1.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> (Predicate<String>)(E -> !E.equals(choiceBox2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem())), choiceBox2.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()));
coicheBox1.setItems(fl1);

FilteredList<String> fl2 = new FilteredList(items);
fl2.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> (Predicate<String>)(E -> !E.equals(choiceBox1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem())), choiceBox1.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()));
coicheBox2.setItems(fl2);
```

Another option is by adding a listener to the selectedItem property in the SelectionModel of the choiceBox, like:

```
ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("length", "area", "volume", "weigth");

choiceBox1.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((P, O, N) -> choiceBox2.setItems(items.filtered(E -> !E.equals(N))));
choiceBox2.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((P, O, N) -> choiceBox1.setItems(items.filtered(E -> !E.equals(N))));
```

Basically both options listen to the current selected item (the `SelectionModel#selectedItem` property), and based on that callback it sets the content of the choicBox list (i.e. The filtered content) . The first option uses the bindings API to create basically the same system as in the second example, but in a bit more fancier way. I think the seconde example should be more understandable.

I hope this gives you a peek into the power of the observable API of javafx, if you have additional questions, feel free to ask